# Bandwidth requirement to live broadcast an event on the internet

Tags: networking, ip, streaming, rtmp

I am assigned on project to live broadcast an event on the internet which may have 50,000 user s. This will be a broadcast so all users will see same live video. My query is what would be my bandwidth requirement in terms of no of users viewing that stream.

1. I am little confused & the reason is does every users need a separate stream of bandwidth in broadcast ?
2. If i would install a server with streaming capability having Bandwidth of 50 Mbps would it be enough considering it is a broadcast.
3. Do i necessarily need to have Class C IP to run streaming server on rtmp protocol.
4. Is is possible to achieve this through RTSP. How do services like Google Hangout Air work? What protocol is used in Hangout and Youtube when live broadcasts are done.

I have read some where the broadcast needs only stream of data to transmit to all users compared to unicast which requires separate stream for every connection/user.

Kindly suggest me solution especially mention if you have such practical experiance.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Normally you'd use multicast for this, but the Internet does not route multicast. So you need a separate stream for each user. You didn't provide a bitrate for your video so we can't tell you what your total bandwidth would be, but let's just say it's 500Kbps. Total bandwidth would be 500Kbps * 50,000 which far exceeds any Internet pipe I know of.

Comment: What would be your suggestion? Can it be achieved through any other model. What protocol or concepts used in Google Hangout Air or Youtube live broadcasts

Comment: @Nawaz Talk to a CDN that provides streaming services. Google/YouTube have the infrastructure to do this in-house; you do not.

Comment: How sites streaming cricket and football matches work. And as far as i know these site don't have such heavy bandwidth connections and they do have such quite good no. of viewers. Appologies if I have asked a wrong question. This is just my curiosity an example will be [link](http://gofirstrow.eu/watch/137666/1/watch-espn.html)

Comment: Can we use Hangout Air or youtube embed for my purpose